# Conditionals not compiling and creating an error

Tags: conditional-statements, swiftui

I have an issue with SwiftUI not accepting the > condition.

Not sure if I am doing someone wrong..

It accepts for example != or == but will not accept either <  or  > conditions.

```
if frequnecyInput > zeroValue {
          Text("Length : \(number / (frequnecyInput ?? 0.00))")
            .font(.largeTitle)
            .color(Color.gray)
            .frame(width: 300.0, height: 40.0)
            .shadow(radius: 8.0)
            .padding()
        }
```

Above code will not compile.

```
if frequnecyInput != zeroValue {
          Text("Length : \(number / (frequnecyInput ?? 0.00))")
            .font(.largeTitle)
            .color(Color.gray)
            .frame(width: 300.0, height: 40.0)
            .shadow(radius: 8.0)
            .padding()
        }
```

Above code will compile.

What am I doing wrong?

Cheers.

Comment: I'll guess that if the line that doesn't build is `frequencyInput > zeroValue` then you haven't posted enough code for us to duplicate. (But, keep in mind that SwiftUI is in beta 3 and yeah, the errors aren't yet much good.) Any chance you could post more code? Maybe a small project that can duplicate your issue? It really helps.

Answer (score 1):

I'd ask what error message you are getting, but it doesn't matter, since compile errors with SwiftUI (at least in beta3) are unhelpful and usually just red herrings.

I'm *guessing* that since you have a `frequnecyInput ?? 0.00` statement that `frequnecyInput` is a `Optional<Double>`, in which case `!=` is a legal statement but `<` is not (`"Binary operator '>' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Double?' and 'Double'"`).

For the record, the following compiles and runs for me:

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView : View {
    private var frequnecyInput: Double? = 1.0
    private var zeroValue: Double? = 0.0
    private var number: Double = 3.0

    var body: some View {
        if (frequnecyInput ?? 0.0) > (zeroValue ?? 0.0) {
            return AnyView(Text("Length : \(number / (frequnecyInput ?? 0.00))")
                .font(.largeTitle)
                .color(Color.gray)
                .frame(width: 300.0, height: 40.0)
                .shadow(radius: 8.0)
                .padding())
        } else {
            return AnyView(Text("None"))
        }

    }
}
```

Hopefully the next beta (which will be released tomorrow) will improve the compiler error messages somewhat.